# Standard properties of trigonemetric functions

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

You have $\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})= \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6})= \frac{1}{2}$
and the interval [$\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}$] has length $\geq 1$ This is used as I'm sure most will be familiar in the proof of divergence of the sequence $\sin(n)$ 
$n \in \mathbb{N}$ in Real Analysis.
Consider the interval [$0,\pi$] for $\sin(x)$. From above the subinterval at which $\sin(x) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ has length $\geq 1$.

Take any $0\leq\delta\leq \frac{1}{2} $ Is it also a standard result that the subinterval at which $\sin(x) \geq \delta$ has length $\geq 1$? 
It would clearly follow by exploiting fact that $\sin(x)$ is increasing on
[$0,\frac{\pi}{2}$] and decreasing on [$\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi$]. For the negative half of sin if you wanted $0\geq\delta\geq -\frac{1}{2} $ you can do same trick and then use periodicity to extend domain to [$-\infty,\infty$]. 
Is this all fine - I am just unsure of what to assume and what not to assume as a "standard" property.

Comment: Yes. Those are correct observations.

Comment: You can use any facts that follow immediately from looking at the graph of $\sin$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$, and the symmetries (incl. periodicity) of this graph. But you cannot use, e.g., that $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: You did not specify why you are asking this. If it is because you want to know what your **teacher** expects, **ask him/her**, not us. If it is for knowing mathematics just for its **own** sake, then simply go and prove everything and **do not assume anything**.

Comment: @user21820 It is what Analysis expects- not what any particular person expects

Comment: Dr Analysis expects you to prove everything.

Comment: just pointing out that the OP is Arcane1729 and the question is edited by Hardy, and it was Hardy (namesake) who noticed the taxicab number 1729 on the way to visit Ramanujan ... :)